# Java reg expression capture string

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string:

```
"(1)name1:content1(2)name2:content2(3)name3:content3...(n)namen:contentn"
```

what I want to do is to capture each of the `name_i` and `content_i`, how can I do this? I should mention that `name_i` is unknown. For example `name1` could be `"abc"`, `name2` could be `"xyz"`.

What I have tried:

```
String regex = "\\(\\d\\)(.*):(.*)(?=\\(\\d\\))";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(0);
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1);
  System.out.println(matcher.group(2);
}
```

But the results is not very good. I also tried `matcher.mathes()`, nothing will be returned.

Comment: You can use [`\(\d+\)(\w+):(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/CrZlzx/1)

Comment: I suggest a less readable, but a more lenient and efficient regex: `"\\(\\d+\\)([^:]+):([^(]*(?:\\((?!\\d+\\))[^(]*)*)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
String s = "(1)name1:content1(2)name2:content2(3)name3:content3...(4)namen:content4";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(\\d+\\)([^:]+):([^(]*(?:\\((?!\\d+\\))[^(]*)*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); 
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/H9UdAc)

**Details**

- `\\(\\d+\\)` - matches `(x)` substring where `x` is 1 or more digits
- `([^:]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `:`
- `:` - a colon
- `([^(]*(?:\\((?!\\d+\\))[^(]*)*)` - Group 2:

  - `[^(]*` - zero or more chars other than `(`
  - `(?:\\((?!\\d+\\))[^(]*)*` - zero or more sequences of:

    - `\\((?!\\d+\\))` - a `(` that is not followed with 1+ digits and `)`
    - `[^(]*` - 0+ chars other than `(`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wCBDiN/1).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This will work if your name and content does not include any non "word"-boundary characters:

```
public static void test(String input){
    String regexpp = "\\(\\d+\\)(\\w+):(\\w+)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexpp);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println("Name: " + m.group(1));
        System.out.println("Content: " + m.group(2));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Name: name1
Content: content1
Name: name2
Content: content2
Name: name3
Content: content3
Name: name99
Content: content99
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But `name_i` is unknown. For example `name1` could be `"abc"`, `name2` could be `"xyz"`.

Comment: You state the exact string in your question. It is probably better to provide a more representative example not to confuse others.

Comment: `:` doesn't need to escaped in regex

Answer (score -1):

Your expression matches greedily - your first group eats up the colon first so it won't be possible to match the entire expression. You can use non-greedy matching (using the question mark as in `*?`) to make your pattern match.

```
String regex = "\\(\\d\\)(.*?):(.*?)(?=\\(\\d\\))";
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. It works better than mine. But still only the first group, i.e., `name1`, `content1`, is returned in the `matcher.group()`.